# App Store Updates: New versions in history, but installed app is old

Tags: macos, server.app

Quick questions (wall of text with details below):

My iTunes is at 11.1.5, the update history says it updated to 11.2.2 - but it actually didn't.

1. Can I clear the update history in the App Store application?
2. Can I "reset" App Store's update logic?
3. Where on the machine is that update config data stored for App
   Store?

I found solutions to download iTunes separately from the Apple website and install it without using App Store. But I would like my software update service to work properly and if it doesn't, I'd like to fix it.

Wall of text with details:

I am using OS X Server on Mavericks with Software Update service. I set the update server url with the profile manager to my server's update service. On the client machine the available updates were shown correctly. I updated iTunes. That seemed to work, because the update progress ran much quicker than would be possible with our DSL speed. Because I thought it would be stuck at some point, I cancelled it and tried to update it again. Then it seemed to contact the Apple server instead of my server's update service (progress bar very slow). I cancelled that. Now iTunes is not listed as an "available update", however, it is listed four times in the update history. The actual iTunes is still the old version. I restarted the mac - iTunes is still old. Can I fix the update system?

EDIT:

Found some time to spend a few minutes on the issue and noticed a file at this location:

`/Users/.../Library/Application Support/App Store/updatejournal.plist`

When I move it away, the history with the duplicate entries is gone from the App Store software, however, App Store won't pick up the new iTunes 11.2.2. (I checked the version of the installed iTunes files - they are at 11.1.5.)